# To update a template, must all registrations be updated?

Tags: azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I can register a device with a template. If I want to update the template for all devices, do I need to update every registration?

In other words, can I register a template in one place and only update that?

Answer (score 1):

You can upload or generate Automation script and add to library and later use this template.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2DSn.png)